# ActiveRecord Linq/NHibernate Linq not building query completely

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

given this function:

```
Public Function Search(ByVal StartIndex As Integer, _
 ByVal MaxResults As Integer, _
 ByVal AccountNumber As String, _
 ByVal LastName As String, _
 ByVal FirstName As String, _
 ByVal DateOfService As String, _
 ByVal CPTCode As String, _
 ByVal Contract As String, _
 ByVal ClaimNumber As String, _
 ByVal PaidAmount As String, _
 ByVal CheckNumber As String, _
 ByVal SortExpression As String, _
 ByRef count As Integer) As RemitLineItemEntity()
```

I am trying to build up where clause one piece at a time based on parameters passed into the function, like so:

```
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(AccountNumber) Then
        If AccountNumber.Contains("%") Then
            remits = remits.Where(Function(r) r.MedicalRecordNumber Like AccountNumber.Replace("%", "*"))
        Else
            remits = remits.Where(Function(r) r.MedicalRecordNumber = AccountNumber)
        End If
    End If
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName) Then
        If LastName.Contains("%") Then
            remits = remits.Where(Function(r) r.LastName Like LastName.Replace("%", "*"))
        Else
            remits = remits.Where(Function(r) r.LastName = LastName)
        End If
    End If
```

... many more if statements for other params

```
        _log.Debug("Start Count query")
        count = remits.Count()
        _log.Debug("End Count query")
```

Calling this function with lastname = "smith", when I get to the `count=remits.Count()` line, watching SQL Profiler it generates sql like this (prettied up from what nhibernate generates) :

```
Select count(*) from remitline
```

instead of what I expected:

```
Select count(*) from remitline where lastname = "smith"
```

What am I doing wrong building up the where clause?  I'm using Castle ActiveRecord 2.1

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to latest version of ActiveRecord (3.0 RC) and this issue went away.